# How to get ngx-mat-select-search to bind to an array and have an output emitter on selection changes?

Tags: angular

I'm using ngx-mat-select-search for a multi-select dropdown with search.

I'm trying to make it a component that:

1. Is given as @Input() a list of values to display
2. The selected values are bound to some array so that the parent component can have access to the current selections.
3. Has an @Output() emitter that tells the parent component an options has been checked/unchecked. Then the parent can do whatever with the values that were bound in 2.

Here's what I have so far: https://github-omyu1h.stackblitz.io

Answer (score 1):

you could remove the reactive form control

```js
public bankMultiCtrl: FormControl = new FormControl();
```

and use the model property you defined in your example

```js
  // 2. selectedValues should be bound to whatever is selected
  @Input() selectedValues: string[] = [];
  // 3. output whenever a change is made to selectedValues
  @Output() selectionChange = new EventEmitter();
```

in your template as follows:

```html
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [ngModel]="selectedValues" (ngModelChange)="selectionChange.emit($event)" placeholder="Banks" [multiple]="true" #multiSelect>
      <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="bankMultiFilterCtrl"></ngx-mat-select-search>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let bank of filteredBanksMulti | async" [value]="bank">
        {{bank}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-omyu1h-juy4ay?file=src/app/examples/02-multiple-selection-example/multiple-selection-example.component.ts